# Blackberry 10 simulator set default screen resolution/detect given IP

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

Right now every time I run the Blackberry 10 simulator (standalone) I have to pick one of four options (Q10 style, Z10 style, and safe mode for either one).

I'd like this to be 'default' Z10 style instead of having to click into the VMWare and type the values. (Sometimes if I'm not quick enough the defaults are picked for me). Any advice?

Comment: Do you really need to reboot it? Can't you just "pause" it?

Comment: I could definitely just pause it. The problem is, if this is running on a CI server or something similar, the simulator may crash or leak memory. I think recovering from the base-state without assistance is really what I need. We could definitely pause but being able to start from scratch would be very valuable.

Comment: I didn't thought about this case. You're right, they are obviously cases where you can't just pause it, and having a way to fix an image to Z10 and another to Q10 is needed. Sadly, I don't know any way to do it, sorry.